# JQGrid Radio Button Posting true false value to server instead of html tag

Tags: radio-button, jqgrid

I have created jqgrid with four columns and first column is radio button, created using formatter. I am passing the grid values to server on click of a save button. But it is posting the html tag as value for radio button column which is inside the formatter (used for creating the radio button) to server. Instead i want to post true (if radio is selected) or false to server. Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the unformat function